# How to write in C starting at a certain point in the buffer?

Tags: c, string

Simple question. I've been trying to find the answer before asking but i dont know if im wording the question right.

I want to write in C using `write(int fd, char* buffer, size)`.

```
char buffer[40];
//just assume the buffer has been read into.
write(fdout,buffer,40);
```

I want to write say starting at index 2 of the buffer so from buffer[2] to the end skipping the first 2 characters. To do this would I have to make another char* and concat the buffer excluding the first 2 characters?

Comment: `buffer+2` will do fine... `offset=2; write(fdout,buffer+offset,40-offset);`

Comment: Or `&buffer[2]` if that feels more comfortable, though I prefer the explicit pointer arithmetic myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a pointer into the proper place in the buffer:

```
write(fdout, &buffer[2], 40-2);
```

Comment: Why change from 38 to 40-2?

Comment: @WizKiz To be more clear regarding the size of the buffer relating to the offset you're writing from.  If the value `2` was a variable, you would plug that variable in both places.